# Rumors and Truths

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My potency to provoke, a smile or weeping,
> Repugnance in my core, I carry its keeping.
> With a fresh dawn, I set forth to explore,
> Guided by directions to engulf and implore.
> Roughly, we are benign cysts, not to fear,
> Held back, a young lover, I hear.

*What am I?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are:

> the four-letter word, **NEWS** - a word associated with *rumors and truths* (depending on whether it may be 'fake news' or thorough journalistic reporting).

*My potency to provoke, a smile or weeping,*

> Receiving new information (i.e. news) from a friend or a media outlet can bring forth emotions, both happy and sad.

*Repugnance in my core, I carry its keeping.*

> *In its core*, NEWS contains the substring '**EW**' - a verbal exclamation made out of *repugnance*.

*With a fresh dawn, I set forth to explore,*

> NEWS begins with '**NEW**', i.e. its 'dawn' (beginning) means '*fresh*'.

*Guided by directions to engulf and implore.*

> The whole word 'NEWS' is spelled solely using letters that are also *compass directions* (North, East, West, South).

*Roughly, we are benign cysts, not to fear,*

> Anagramming the word ('*roughly*') yields **[WENS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wen)**, a word meaning 'benign cysts'.

*Held back, a young lover, I hear.*

> When reversed ('*held back*'), 'SWEN' sounds a bit like '[**SWAIN**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swain)', a word meaning 'a young male lover'.

Comment: Goodness! Spare my riddle someday haha. Grreat job. Super quick! :)